# Rails: How to change value of an ENV variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While running rspec, I want to change value of an ENV variable. I know, there are multiple options. But i want to set in command line, while issuing rspec command.

For example

> c:\>rspec WRITE_OUTPUT=true

Comment: I tried this command: `WRITE_OUTPUT=true rspec` and it can get `ENV[WRITE_OUTPUT]` with value = true. 
Tested with rails app on MacOS and Ubuntu. I'm not sure it works on Windows. Could you try this?

Comment: Yeh, this works in Mac. But not in Windows.Thanks